# How to load and get pixel value of a 16-bit single channel PNG image?

Tags: android, png

I tried to load a 16-bit single channel PNG image in Android and get the value of each pixels.

I used function "BitmapFactory.decodeStream" and get the value of pixels directly. I got the pixel values like "-16250872".

How can I get the correct values of this type of image in Android?

---

```
InputStream ist= null;
      try {
          ist = getAssets().open(pic_PATH2);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  Bitmap bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ist);
  int width = bmp2.getWidth();//get the width of the image
  int height = bmp2.getHeight();//get the height of the image
  float[][] Px2  = new float[width][height];
  for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
      {
          Px2[j][i] = bmp2.getPixel(j, i);
      }
```

Comment: I bet you are getting the value `0xFFF7F7F8` but you *chose* to interpret and display it as a signed integer. Which is a bad choice, to view an RGBA value in (presumably). But … we cannot tell without seeing your source code.

Comment: Thank you for your replay. I have edited my question. I think my image is not a rgb format. It can not be converted directly. I get pixel value like -1.6777216E7 which is supposed to be 0 in the original image.